# "Argument not specified for parameter", but it is specified

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0

I'm trying to pass some parameters into a data annotation, and it is rejecting my named parameter.  See below:

[image]

It's the same exact syntax in **[Microsoft's documentation for the TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx#Y1800)**, except in the documentation they have an uppercase N, but intellisense on the parameter in VS asks for a lower case n.

**Edit:**  After getting 2 good answers, I just wanted to explain why I thought I could do this in the first place.  It looks like the constructor was updated, but the tooltip wasn't, because this is what shows up when you get the syntax prompt:

[image]

And I needed to be able to specify schema.  But now I've found another way to do this.

**Edit #2**:  Why I was trying named parameters in the first place; because this wasn't working.

[image]

**Edit #3:** Apparently I missed trying this syntax, which works.  Figured it out thanks to Damien.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong [`TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The one from the `DataAnnotations` namespace expects a [constructor (non-named) `name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.tableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter.

Comment: @TomHalladay - re: your edit - parameters shown without `[]` brackets are required (they're constructor parameters). Parameters within `[]` brackets are optional (they're actually properties of the attribute)

Comment: That part I knew, but if you check out the (new) third picture, when I tried to leverage the syntax it was telling me was available (Name, Schema), it wouldn't let me specify schema.  I was hoping I could get around it by naming all the parameters, but that wasn't working either...  Oh what fun..

Answer (score 1):

Name isn't an optional parameter for `TableAttribute`.  You don't need to prefix it with `name:=` at all.  Just type as:

```
<Table("SYSTEMSETTING")>
Public Class MyTableClass
```